# OpenReadTaskAsync how to obtain Content type of uri?

Tags: .net, webclient, contenttype

Consider the following code in a .Net service

```
public async Task<Stream> GetBlob(string url) {

   WebClient client = new WebClient();
   Stream download = await client.OpenReadTaskAsync(url);
   _operationContext.OperationCompleted += delegate
      {
          download.Close();
          download.Dispose();
      };
   return download;
}
```

This works, I get binary data back but not with the correct content type (I get application/octet-stream as it should be image/jpeg). How to pass/obtain the correct mimetype?

Comment: Isn't the content correct? An image *is* binary data. The returned content type depends on what the server decides to send, unless you specify the `Accept` header. In this case the server has to send the response in the specified format, making any conversions if necessary

Comment: the content is fine. but if the url points to a resource with a mimetype other than "application/octet-stream" i would expect it to copy the mimetype also.